# Commutative diagram of a topological Markov chain

Tags: dynamical-systems

I want to see that the following diagram commutes,

[image]

where $\sigma_A$ is a topological Markov chain, this is, we define the set,

$$\Omega_N= \{\omega=(\ldots,\omega_{-1},\omega_0,\omega_1,\ldots) | \omega_j \in \{0,1,\ldots N\}, i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Then we can take the shift function

$$\sigma_N : \Omega_N \to \Omega_N$$

$$\sigma_N(\omega)=\omega '$$

where we have defined $\omega_i'=\omega_{i+1}$. With this in mind we take a $N \times N$ matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{0}^{N-1}$ whose entries are either zeros or ones, then we define

$$\Omega_A= \{\omega \in \Omega_N| a_{\omega_j, \omega_{j+i}}=1, i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

So $\sigma|_{\Omega_{A}}=\sigma_{A}$ is called a topological Markov chain. We have another set to define,

$$B_2= \left \{\omega \in \Omega_{2} | \forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, m>n, \left|\sum_{i=n}^{m}(-1)^{\omega_i} \right|≤2 \right \}$$

and $S_2=\sigma_2{|_{B_{2}}}$, so I want a matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{0}^{N-1}$ and a function $H :\Omega_{2} \to B_2$ such that

$$H \circ \sigma_A=S_2 \circ H$$

Then I chose

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0& 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) 
 $$

after using other $2\times2$ examples, but I don't know to take $H$.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Your notation seems pretty opaque, some expansion would probably be good.

Comment: Ok, let me edit :), just a second

Comment: @Ian Ready :) I've edited my post :)

Comment: @Ian is my post now clear? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The map is the easy part. The main problem is the matrix. Doesn't $N=4$ look much better to solve the problem? Why?

Comment: Well I thought that N=3 could worked because I had some issues with N=2  but I think N=4 is have the same to say as N=3 right?

Comment: Let me ask in another way: why do you think that the dynamics on $B_2$ is a Markov chain? It is in your title. But it is not... Really, you need to find a way to think how to find an appropriate matrix $A$. Where does your $A$ come from after all? My suggestion (which works): take $N=4$ ($N=3$ does not).

Comment: Can elaborate please? Sorry but I can't get your idea :)

Comment: @JohnB so can point your idea again please, is because I can't get your point, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JohnB I have modified a little bit my title so now I am saying that I'm working with only 1 topological markov chain $\sigma_A$

Comment: Have been trying to complete a few things, sorry. Do try odd-odd, odd-even, even-odd, even-even (four of them...).

Comment: @JohnB I am back,no problem jajajaja sorry the delay too,  so you mean that matrix right ?

Comment: @JonhB Is it right ? jajaj I  begin to think it is not jajaj